# Pymongo: How to update many documents in a collection setting as values elements of a list

Tags: python, mongodb, list, pymongo

I have a collection and I would like to update multiple documents at the same time. The problem is that I have two lists, one with the ids that I want to use as a filter and the second one has the values that need to be updated for the corresponding id, so the order is important.

Right now I am doing a for loop to perform the update on every single pair of (id, value) but I don't know if this is the most efficient way

```py
for d, v in zip(document_ids, values):
    db[collection_name].update_one({'_id':d]}, {'$set':{'article_id':v]}})
```